# Is it a bad style of using key: value instead of :key => value in a hash of Ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9

The teams I joined discourage using `key: value` even for a new project, despite it requires less keystrokes and is more alike JavaScript (I do not like PHP things).

Is it considered a bad style in Ruby's community? Do not think this is subjective question. I am just asking about the common trends.

Comment: [This article](http://logicalfriday.com/2011/06/20/i-dont-like-the-ruby-1-9-hash-syntax/) gives a few arguments against the new syntax. Many people seem to like it though. In general I wouldn't say it's considered bad style.

Comment: Whether or not it is bad style is subjective.  Whether or not the Ruby community as a whole considers it to be bad style is _not_ subjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) says "When the keys of your hash are symbols use the Ruby 1.9 hash literal syntax.".

The main reason I use the 1.8-style syntax is that I currently use a few analysis tools that either don't work on Ruby 1.9 (heckle ... at least not yet) or don't work as well on 1.9 (ruby-prof).

Answer (score 0):

As long as the project is consistent throughout in one style or the other there's no problem.

If you're planning on supporting Ruby < 1.9, then of course you'll want to stick with `:key => value`.

Comment: That's the thing we were talking about. My coworkers argued that it is impossible to be "consistent", since we often need to use non-symbols as keys here and there in a rails project.

Comment: @powerboy: If you use MongoDB you'll have to use `=>` since symbols like `:$set` cannot be represented in the "new" style.

Comment: That's what I was trying to say in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think both can be used together, I don't see any problem. It's just a matter of taste.

I tend to use the new form as it's faster to type, and to me it seems cleaner, but there are cases where the old form would be better, like when you need a string key:

```
:"my_key" => "my value"
```