# accessing instance methods inside a ruby/Rails class but outside an instance method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to send the count on an active Record object's association to the [redis-object gem](https://github.com/nateware/redis-objects)

```
class Post > ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments

   include Redis::Objects
   value :redis_comment_count, :default => self.comments.count
end
```

PS: setting :default => "string" works just fine

but this does not work because self at that place in the code (its not in a method definition)  refers to the class definition of Post and not a post instance itself. I was trying to figure out if this was something that was even possible to do.

Am I making sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it looks like you will have to go the longer way of setting up save callbacks for your comments. I browsed through the gem and it doesn't look like passing a proc for calling later is supported yet (see [here](https://github.com/nateware/redis-objects/blob/269252174f95f9a5c81d8e6ca9bb94713e5f6233/lib/redis/value.rb)).

**By the way**:

Besides the fact that you are calling the class method and not the instance method, `self.comments.count` is evaluated when the class is loaded, right there when you call:

```
 value :redis_comment_count, :default => self.comments.count

 # This becomes:
 # value :redis_comment_count, :default => 1  # Example
```

and not every time that the redis-objects gem uses `value_options[:default]`.

This value will keep getting re-evaluated if your class keeps getting reloaded, as in the case of the default setup for the development environment. However, in the production environment where we usually have `cache_classes` enabled, this value will be evaluated only whenever the Rails application boots up and loads your models.

Passing a proc would work if this were supported.

Comment: What would I pass into the proc?

Comment: Passing a proc is not (yet) supported, however. :-)

Comment: I know ... I'm just curious what I would pass in if I did. I'm going to fork the gem and make it work that way

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
value :redis_comment_count, default: -> { self.comments.count}
```

That's using Ruby 1.9's [new hash syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412242/what-are-the-benefits-of-the-new-hash-syntax-in-ruby-1-9) along with the 'stab' or [lambda operator](http://ruby.about.com/od/newinruby191/qt/LambdaOperator.htm).

Comment: yes. I used the old ruby style of default: lambda { self.comments.count } and that returns a proc, which doesn't work for me, I need it to return the actual value, but when I try lambda { self.comments.count }.call I got the error "NoMethodError: undefined method `comments' for #<Class:0x007fa63b841708>" when I hit reload! in rails console