# Difference between :remote => true and remote: true

Tags: ruby

What's the difference between these two options? They seem to do the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are the same the difference is Hash syntax for 1.9+ Ruby versions and 1.8- Ruby versions:

```
# Ruby 1.8 Syntax
{:this => 'syntax', 'is' => 'fun'}
# Ruby 1.9 syntax
{this: 'syntax', more: 'fun'}
```

Check this one as well: "[What are the benefits of the new hash syntax in Ruby 1.9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412242/what-are-the-benefits-of-the-new-hash-syntax-in-ruby-1-9)"

As written in the referred post:
  It just looks nicer--it's syntactic sugar; it ends up being the same thing.

Comment: Please elaborate that your second example is in fact broken.

Comment: What's broken? If the compiler is complaining, could that mean you're running on Ruby 1.8?

Comment: thanks @lorefnon fixed, Katana314  there was an extra quote

Comment: Ok, the author changed the answer... http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/29953010/1

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. The first is the older syntax for defining a key value pair for hashes. The second was introduced with Ruby 1.9 (I think).

If you're using a version of Ruby pre 1.9 you will have to use the first syntax, otherwise you should use the second syntax.

Comment: There is a difference. There are no "older" and "newer" syntaxes, the JavaScript-style syntax only applies to *some* symbols in Hash literals, if your keys are not a limited set of symbols then you need to use the hashrocket.