# Rails button_to send get query instead of post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rails 4 button_to

```
<%= button_to 'Send', {:controller => "feedback", :action => "send_feedback"}, class: "btn btn-success pull-right" %>
```

In API documentation i saw, that default behaviour for button_to is to send POST queries, but in log:

```
Started GET "/?name=%D0%98%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8C&email=silend%40inbox.ru&text=ghfhfg&authenticity_token=MbPeULaBSsjRmf1415AUfwQOLl5%2FkpOUzbOyJnBRMXa7%2Fgi6yyoTn8kSsVR3sFEkVxMH%2FN%2FfDEFfwWpN%2Bjc5NA%3D%3D"
```

In routes.rb:

```
post "feedback/send_feedback" => "feedback#send_feedback"
```

Everything works fine when i add "formmethod = post" in result html inside browser, but how to change it with rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with form, not button_to helper.
I wrote path to my controller/action with method in form tag:

```
<%= form_tag("/feedback/send_feedback", method: "post", class: "form-horizontal") do %>
```

and change button_to to submit_tag

```
<%= submit_tag "Отправить", class: "btn btn-success pull-right" %>
```

And now it works

Answer (score 1):

You should set the method to use:

```
<%= button_to 'Send', {controller: "feedback", action: "send_feedback"}, method: :post, class: "btn btn-success pull-right" %>
```

see the docs [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to)

For the example:

```
<%= button_to 'Save', {controller: "links", action: "create"}, method: :post, class: "btn btn-success pull-right" %>
```

this code was generated:

```
<form class="button_to" action="/links" method="post">
<input class="btn btn-success pull-right" type="submit" value="Save">
<input type="hidden" value="kT0h/RaXsLfOGouIYKS6Td767VF1+q72GFl6XIIwzcbd+/Au/7gvTeGRf5ajMMV9Ds3PO7U5bF4/O5zKgJWzqQ==" name="authenticity_token">
</form>
```

Also use the new Hash sintaxe, see [What are the benefits of the new hash syntax in Ruby 1.9?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11412242/1006863)

Comment: Thank you for answer, but with method: post - syntax error, method: "post" - still GET query. Also tried to use old syntax like :method => :post still the same

Comment: Error with suggested syntax is - ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `post' for #<#<Class:0x007fc7d2bd5b18>:0x007fc7d2bdbdd8>)

Comment: @TorryAshwood I litle mistake, change 'post' to ':post'. I have edited the answer.

Comment: It generates GET query, html for button is <input class="btn btn-success pull-right" type="submit" value="Send">